# After upgrading Spring Roo from 1.2.5 to 1.3.1 I am getting "No metadata provider is currently registered to provide metadata..."

Tags: spring-roo

The full error displayed in the Roo Shell window is:

No metadata provider is currently registered to provide metadata for identifier 'MID:org.springframework.roo.project.ProjectMetadata#the_project' (class 'MID:org.springframework.roo.project.ProjectMetadata')

I tried upgrading STS in two ways:

1. I applied upgrades to my existing STS
2. I downloaded new version of STS and added latest version of Roo

Both produce same error in roo shell window.

**No AspectJ files are now being generated by Roo.**

Can anyone explain how to fix this please?

Many thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to delete ".spring_roo_pgp.bpg" file in your user home

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It got my roo shell working again. However due to the lack of support from the community, I have decided to drop Roo as a development tool.